# Full width of image in jQuery

Tags: jquery

How can I know in jQuery the height of an image loaded with:

```
style="width:100%; height: auto;"
```

The width screen in mobile device is ever different, and i dont like the effect "jump" when the page is loading. I hope I was clear. Thanks

Comment: did you try `jQuery('img').hieght()`

Comment: If you also want mobile devices to use actual screen res, instead of a default set of screen dimensions and scaling, start by adding `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` to your page(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following (see if it helps :) ):

```
alert("width: " + $("#imgRandom").width() +"\nHeight:  "+$("#imgRandom").height() );
```

fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/6dnSM/

i hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks maverickosama92; it's perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can quite easily get the height using [`height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) and [`outerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/), for example:

```
var imgHeight = $('img.image-class').height();
```

Or:

```
var imgHeight = $('img.image-class').outerHeight(false); // the argument indicates whether to include the margin
```

Comment: BenM in both cases imgHeight value is null;  maybe because my image isn't yet loaded?

Comment: this is my html: <img src="http://www.site.com/img/122/big.jpg" style="width:100%; height: auto;" class="classheight">

Comment: Yes, but you might need to add it to the `load()` function of the your image too.

Comment: I'd like set the height of the div before of image is loading; because now during the loading a page from smartphones there is a annoying "gap".

Comment: You can't do that unless you know the width and height of the image before it's loaded. You'll need to calculate the ratio of the image, and then work out the correct height - all of which need the original image to have already been loaded.